# __toString does not output

Tags: php, oop, tostring

I found the entry PHP OOP - toString not working but it does not address my issue as I believe I am calling the magic method properly...

Here is my code:

```
class Alerts {

    public $message;
    public $type;
    public $output;

    public function __construct($message_id)
    {
    include 'con.php';          
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE id = :message_id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':message_id' => $message_id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $this->type = $row['type'];
        $this->message = $row['message'];  
    }
    }

    public function __toString (){
        $output ='';
        $output .= "<div class='" . $this->type . "'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button>";
        $output .= "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>&nbsp;<strong>";
        $output .= $this->message;
        $output .= "</strong> </div>";
        return $output;
     } 

}
```

It works if I call:

```
$message_id = 6;

$alert = new Alerts($message_id);
$output ='';
$output .= "<div class='" . $alert->type . "'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button>";
$output .= "<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>&nbsp;<strong>";
$output .= $alert->message;


$output .= "</strong> </div>";
```

on the page but not if I use:

```
$message_id = 6;

$alert = new Alerts($message_id);
echo $alert->output;
```

I am a newbie with PHP OOP so you help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The `__toString()` method is automatically called when an object is used in the context of a string. Just do `echo $alert;`

Comment: Not sure why you think you need `->output`... No language I know uses that to invoke `toString`.

Comment: Also don't forget if you're trying to actually modify the public property `$output`, you must use `$this->output` in the context of a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring):

> The `__toString()` method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string. For example, what `echo $obj;` will print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR` level error is emitted.

By that logic, doing `echo $alert->output;` will just output the blank property `public $output;` that was declared in your class. Two reasons that `public $output` is blank and doesn't get modified is:

1. You don't access `$this->output` in the context of the `__toString()` method.
2. `__toString()` doesn't get called when you access any method or property of the object, *only* when you treat an object like a string.

What you actually should do if you decide to utilize `__toString()` is:

```
echo $alert;
```

Comment: Hi sjagr,  Thanks you for your reply I did as you suggested and used echo $alert and it printed out but the I get the error after: ***Catchable fatal error: Method Alerts::__toString() must return a string value in /var/www/vhosts/dev-roe-vti.org/httpdocs/mdashboard/login.php on line 130***

Comment: @janetspagnol You're welcome. If my solution helped you, it is appropriate to mark off the solution as accepted by clicking the grey checkmark below the up/down arrows to the left of my answer so that it turns green. [See this meta article for more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Here is the var_dump if it  helps
object(Alerts)#3 (2) { ["message"]=> string(78) "We are sorry but we do not have a Senior Mentor that matches these credentials" ["type"]=> string(18) "alert alert-danger" }

Comment: @janetspagnol Did you modify your `__toString()` method? As the error says, you must be returning something other than a string. Either way, this should be addressed in a new question as it is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @janetspagnol The `var_dump` is not helpful at all. What is in your `__toString()` method?

Comment: I changed my __toString to:

` public function __toString (){
  $output ='This is a test';
  echo $output;
  }`

and I still get the error: Catchable fatal error: Method Alerts::__toString() must return a string value in /var/www/vhosts/dev-roe-vti.org/httpdocs/mdashboard/login.php on line 130

Comment: @janetspagnol **Do not `echo` anything in your `__toString()` method.** Leave it alone, exactly like it was in your question. Or if you must change how it works and test it with your test phrase, do `public function __toString() { $output = 'This is a test'; return $output; }`. Just like the error says, **the `return` value must be a string!**

Comment: @janetspagnol No problem.. Remember, when something breaks, it happens for a reason. Just like when you lose something, you should retrace your steps to figure out how you got there. As you learn, don't change a bunch of things at once but instead tweak one thing at a time.

Comment: Good advice...  OOP has been a steep learning curve for me but at least one more piece is in place now